# Grafana table that shows top 5 objects from an Array

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm trying to create a table that shows the top 5 nested objects in an array.
My documents look something like this:

```
{
 "_id": 1,
 "workers": [
     {
       "worker_id": 1,
       "units": [
          {
            "unit_id": 1,
            "time": 100
          },
          {
            "unit_id": 2,
            "time": 200
          },
          {
            "unit_id": 3,
            "time": 300
          },
          {
            "unit_id": 4,
            "time": 400
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "worker_id": 2,
       "units": [
          {
            "unit_id": 11,
            "time": 1000
          },
          {
            "unit_id": 12,
            "time": 200
          },
          {
            "unit_id": 13,
            "time": 300
          },
          {
            "unit_id": 14,
            "time": 350
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
}
```

I would like to have two columns in the table. One column with the _id of the document and the other with the unit_id. In the second column should be only the top five units that have the highest time.

Is this possible with Grafana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For computing the top 5 entries from the nested Object, you can use simple-json-datasource plugin. You can create a simple Webapp which does the JSON Parsing logic and return the data in the format you want